# How to pass angular data to circular-progress?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have these code to pass data from controller to view:

```
                    <div class="subject-name subject-eng">
                        {{SubjectData['eng']['subject']}}  <!-- Works -->
                        <br/>
                        {{SubjectData['eng']['value']}} <!-- Works -->
                        <br/>
                        {{SubjectData['eng']['color']}}  <!-- Works -->
                    </div>
                    <circular-progress
                        value = "{{SubjectData['eng']['value']}}"  <!-- Did not Works -->
                        max="100"
                        orientation="1"
                        radius="36"
                        stroke="5"
                        base-color="#fff"
                        progress-color="yellow"
                        iterations="100"
                        animation="easeInOutCubic"
                    ></circular-progress>
```

However, the data passed to `value` in `circular-progress` does not work at all. What is the right way to pass data to `circular-progress value`?

Comment: Where did you get the `circular-progress` element from? And could update your question to include everything we need to reproduce it ourselves in your code? (at least the relevant external scripts)

Comment: maybe try to use ng-value instead of value. But as leroydev says, it depends on circular-progress component/directive

Comment: ng-value worked very well, but the directives `circular-progress` does not read ng-value.. how I can make it?

Comment: @leroydev thanks, here the source for my circular-progress:
https://github.com/serkanyersen/angular-circular-progress

Comment: @Imran the github page you linked doesn't seem to be the same one you're using in this question, are you sure you linked the right one? (the directive name and the options in use don't match, those do match [this project](https://github.com/pistou/angular-circular-progress))

Comment: You were right @leroydev hahaha...

Comment: You save my day @leroydev...  I found the solution:
https://github.com/pistou/angular-circular-progress/blob/master/demo/index.html --- See line 56.

Comment: Sometimes I need to ask then I can find the solution by myself...you all inject the idea...thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [leroydev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5334137/leroydev), you save my day. I found the solution by modify the codes to be like this

```
                <circular-progress
                    value = "SubjectData.eng.value"  <!-- Works perfectly! -->
                    max="100"
                    orientation="1"
                    radius="36"
                    stroke="5"
                    base-color="#fff"
                    progress-color="yellow"
                    iterations="100"
                    animation="easeInOutCubic"
                ></circular-progress>
```

I found the solution by read the instruction at line 56:

[pistou/angular-circular-progress](https://github.com/pistou/angular-circular-progress/blob/master/demo/index.html)

[image]